# Laravel Runtime exception

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, while running  http://localhost:8000/ in my browser i'm getting the below error

```
RuntimeException in compiled.php line 13230:
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

My compiled.php line 13230 lies below :-

```
 public function __construct($key, $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC')
{
    $key = (string) $key;
    if (static::supported($key, $cipher)) {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->cipher = $cipher;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.');
    }
}
```

I got this error after the command 'composer update'.How can i clear this?

Comment: did you try with new "key" : `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: Ya while doing that i,m getting the error No such file or directory

Comment: I cleared this by a fresh Laravel installation in the directory again